# Where did the idea of the 'City in Bottle' Originate?

Tags: myth-identification, arabic

Where did the well known trope of a 'City in a Bottle', as associated with middle eastern mythology, originate?

It is referenced in modern culture (see the City in a Bottle Magic the Gathering Card, Sandman #50: Ramadan by Neil Gaiman, etc), and is always associated with the middle east, Arabia in particular. I thought that it originated somewhere in the 1001 Nights, but I have not been able to locate the particular story.

Can anyone shed light on the origins of this idea?

Comment: Hi, do you have any sort of evidence for this being mythological rather than a SF trope? The obvious point of reference for me is RA Heinlein's short story "Universe".  This may do better over on [SF&F](https://scifi.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'll try it over in SF as well. Thanks for the tip. I posted it here because the idea is always presented as being part of the mythical history of the middle east. This historical aspect makes it seem like a myth to my mind

Comment: Cross-post at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/205965/4918 . In the future, if you ask a question in two forums, please link them both ways.